# GRUB broken 'error: unknown partition'

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows, grubrescue

So, here's the story of this problem

I have my work laptop dualbooted with Windows7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I was doing preparations for a tutorial on openGL I wanted to do and I installed some packages, namely, libxmu-dev and libxi-dev. However, one of these changed like 20 packages that were largely the same but with xorg-* instead of xserver-* prefixes.
When I rebooted several peripherals didn't work.
I mistakenly destroyed the partition that held Ubuntu after making my backups but when I rebooted this message was lying in wait for me.

```
error: unknown partition  
grub rescue:
```

I tried using *ls* to move around the partitions but no matter what I do I always get the same message.

```
error: unknown partition
```

I even tried reinstalling Ubuntu but the install process failed when it reached the grub configuration.
What do I do?
PS: Sorry If this is a common question, I read around the forums and everyone could read and modify their partitions on first try, not my case however.

Comment: You should be able to reinstall from a live disc, it shouldn't matter how messed up the previous install is, as it will get totally wiped. Is your bootloader somewhere else besides in the ubuntu install?

Comment: During the installation it said that the bootloader was in _/dev/mmblck0_ but such partition didn't exist. When I tried reinstalling it just said that grub couldn't be found and it was a fatal error, followed by the grub rescue prompt after a reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Francisco
mmblck0 is (propably) a SD Card in your laptop. I have similar problem and I was forced to reinstall grub from live CD. Some BIOS and GRUB don't read SD Cards for boot, so this is the problem. I think that solution proposed by RhZ is correct. You should boot from LiveCD login to your machine by chroot and then reinstall GRUB on any bootable partition.

Comment: When in doubt, reinstalling is always a decent if imperfect way to get things right.

Comment: Surprisingly, this was the problem.  
After I removed the SD card GRUB complied to the rebuild process and I could get things right again.  
Thanks.